# How to read Double from UInt64 on node.js Buffer?

Tags: node.js, date, buffer, 32bit-64bit

I want to read an **UInt64BE** and convert it to **Double**.
How can I do that?

I convert **Double** to **UInt64BE** as following:

```
var time = Date.now();
buffer.writeUInt32BE(parseInt(time / 0xffffffff, 10), 0);
buffer.writeUInt32BE(parseInt(time & 0xffffffff, 10), 4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(8),
    time = Date.now(),

// convert number to hex
var hex = time.toString(16);
while(hex.length < 16)
    hex = '0' + hex;

// write number as UInt64
buffer.write(hex, 0, 8, 'hex');

// read UInt64 as hex and convert to Double
var num = parseInt(buffer.toString('hex', 0, 8), 16);

console.log(num === time);
```